# Getting blank window in swing gui

Tags: java, swing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [paintComponent () never executes on a JFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077156/paintcomponent-never-executes-on-a-jframe)

I am using the following code to dispaly two strings and i'm drawing them directly on jfame instead of adding them as component or to a jpanel.But Why am i getting a blank window instead of getting Strings.Where am i wrong?

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class SimpleAttributes extends JFrame{

SimpleAttributes()
{

    super("Simple Attributes");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(300, 200);
    //setUndecorated(true);
    Container cp=this.getContentPane();
    cp.setBackground(new Color(0,200,0,0));

    setVisible(true);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    Graphics2D g2=(Graphics2D)g.create();
    g2.setColor(Color.RED);
    g2.drawString("One", 10, 10);

    g.drawString("Two", 10,40);

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){public void run(){new SimpleAttributes();}});
}

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JFrame is not a component, therefor there's no `paintComponent()` function for it. [See the API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html).

Comment: yep. Another reason to use the `@Override` annotation. 1+ for the good pick-up. Also, the original poster should draw inside of a JPanel and use the JPanel's `paintComponent(...)` override rather than drawing directly in a JFrame.

Comment: So,is there no way to draw those two strings from the paint(Graphics g)

Comment: Re @Naveen: you can start playing with `paint()`, but I wouldn't recommend that. You have to do some pixel-math-magic to always take into account the offset of the dialog's header for instance. I would recommend creating a new JPanel with `paintComponent()`.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned the above is incorrect there is no such method, (I was to fast at typing) and thinking about JPanels.

what you can do is create your own `Container` and override the `paint()` method then use that as your `ContentPane` by `frame.setContentPane(Container con)`:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class SimpleAttributes extends JFrame {

    SimpleAttributes() {

        super("Simple Attributes");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(300, 200);
        //setUndecorated(true);
        setContentPane(new MyContainer());
        getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(0, 200, 0, 0));

        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new SimpleAttributes();
            }
        });
    }
}

class MyContainer extends Container {

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2.drawString("One", 10, 10);
        g.drawString("Two", 10, 40);
    }
}
```

as noted in a comment on one answer you can use the `paint()` of the `JFrame` just compensate for the offset of the dialog's header :

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class SimpleAttributes extends JFrame {

    SimpleAttributes() {

        super("Simple Attributes");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(300, 200);
        //setUndecorated(true);
        getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(0, 200, 0, 0));

        setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2.setColor(Color.RED);
    g2.drawString("One", 10, 10);//wont show
        g2.drawString("One", 50, 50);//will show
        g.drawString("Two", 40, 40);//will show
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new SimpleAttributes();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

but all of thats just going to give you more headaches why not just do it the preferred way? A `JPanel` and override `paintComponent(Graphics g);`

Comment: Thanx DavidKroukamp ,but is there no way that i can draw on jframe and make it visible through the content pane (maybe by making content pane transparent).