# How do you draw an object from another class?

Tags: java

I am trying to make a greeting card in java that draws objects from other classes, and I can get my program to compile, its just that the resulting window I get from each draw only comes up as a blank grey screen. I don't really understand how java GUI works so any tips help.

This is the code of the class whose object I'm trying to draw.
I have some methods and variables I'm not using yet.

Sun class code

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.Color;


public class Sun extends ShapeComponent
{
   private double x;
   private double y;
   private double width;
   private double height;

   
   public Sun(double anX, double aY, double w, double h)
   {
      x = anX;
      y = aY;
      width = w;
      height = h;
   }

   
   public void draw(Graphics2D g2)
   {
    g2.setColor (Color.orange);
    g2.fillArc (100,20,80,80,0,360);
    g2.drawLine (95,55,75,55);
    g2.drawLine (140,105,140,125);
    g2.drawLine (140,15,140,0);
    g2.drawLine (185,60,205,60);
    g2.drawLine (105,35,85,25);
    g2.drawLine (120,20,105,5);
    g2.drawLine (100,80,80,90);
    g2.drawLine (115,100,100,120);
    g2.drawLine (175,5,160,20);
    g2.drawLine (205,25,175,35);
    g2.drawLine (205,90,175,80);
    g2.drawLine (175,120,160,100);
   }
   
   public void translate(int dx, int dy)
   {
      x += dx;
      y += dy;
   }
}
```

I tried to draw the sun like this in my SceneComponent class but all I'm getting is that grey rectangle with no shapes.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class ShapeComponent extends JComponent
{  
    public ShapeComponent(){
        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        jf.setTitle("Greeting Card");
        jf.setSize(480, 600);
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics2D g2){
        super.paintComponent(g2);
        Sun sun = new Sun(5,65,55,66);
        sun.draw(g2);
    }
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

        new ShapeComponent();

    }
}
```

Comment: The most important thing you're missing is a "paint()" method.  Look at this source file: [WeatherWizard.java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/basic2d/examples/WeatherWizard.java)( then review against this tutorial:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/basic2d/.  Or Google for "Java 2D graphics tutorial".

Answer (score 0):

Your `paintComponent` method is actually never called and therefore the sun isn’t drawn. This is because the `paintComponent` method actually overrides the `paintComponent` method of the JComponent you created when you stated

```
new ShapeComponent();
```

However, you create a `JFrame` in the constructor and display that instead of the JComponent. Simply, the `paintComponent` method that you override belongs to a `JComponent` that is not displayed. So, to fix this you need to override the `paintComponent` method of a JPanel which can then be added to a JFrame that you create.

One way to do this is to have your ShapeComponent class extend `JPanel`. However, a more suiting name could be DrawTest:

```
public class DrawTest extends JPanel {

    public Sun sun;

    public DrawTest() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setTitle(“Greeting Card”);
        f.setSize(480, 600);
        f.add(this);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        initializeShapes();

    }

    public void initializeShapes() {
        sun = new Sun(…);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        sun.draw(g2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DrawTest();
    }
}
```

Here, the `paintComponent` method is overriding the `paintComponent` of the JPanel which is then added to a JFrame, which has been initialized and displayed in the constructor.

I added a method to initialize shapes as initializing objects in the paintComponent loop can cause unwanted problems when, for example,
you want to translate the sun. Also, if you want to translate make sure the draw method in the sun is dependent on the sun’s location, x and y.

Moreover, your Sun class does not need to extend ShapeComponent or DrawTest so you can get rid of that extends. However, an abstract ShapeComponent class can be useful if you are planning to have multiple shapes. In that case, Sun can extend ShapeComponent. If this is the case, when you create a ShapeComponent class it does not need to contain any initialization of the frame. Rather, it should have methods such as translate and draw which subclasses, like Sun, can override.

Comment: Thank You! This really clears things up, I was wondering why it wasn't drawing.

Comment: How come when I type your code, the Override gets the error "method does not override or implement a method from a supertype".

Comment: Ah, I have not used Java swing in awhile and forgot JFrame is not a JComponent. Please refer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077156/paintcomponent-never-executes-on-a-jframe. You’ll  need to override the paintComponent method of a JPanel. My apologies

Comment: @P0RTSIDE I have edited my post, you must use a JPanel and add to a JFrame

Comment: Hm, this program compiles but when I run it, it just continuously makes new windows until my computer CPU caps at 100% and I have to close the program manually whereupon I'm prompted with "The operation could not be completed".

Comment: @P0RTSIDE Does your sun class extend DrawTest? If so, that is the problem. Don’t have the Sun class extend anything.

Comment: @P0RTSIDE Sure, this should have been first try, sorry for the hassle.